# Set path to thumbnail using bootstrap on rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to set path to thumbnail areas using bootstrap on rails.
I've been trying to achieve it by using an anchor tag, however I am not sure how to implement path, not url, to an anchor tag.
In particular, I want to set "answer_path" as transition destination. 
Could you tell me how to do it?

```
#homes/home.html.erb
<div class="row">
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#" class="" > <-------Anchor tag
        <div class="caption">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="text-left"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}.png?d=identicon" class="user_image"></li>
            <li>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><%= question.user.name %></li>
                <li><%= question.user.title %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p>
            <%= question.body %>
          </p>
          <p>
            <div class = "answer">
              <% @answer = question.answers.highest[0] %>
              <% if @answer == nil then %>
                No Answer
              <% else %>
                <%= render @answer %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </p>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Re-ask</a></li>
            <li><%= link_to raw("Answer"), new_answer_path(question_id: question.id), method: :get, class: "btn btn-default" %></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
     </a> <-------Anchor tag
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <%= link_to answer_path(question.answer) do %> <-------Anchor tag
        <div class="caption">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="text-left"><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}.png?d=identicon" class="user_image"></li>
            <li>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><%= question.user.name %></li>
                <li><%= question.user.title %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p>
            <%= question.body %>
          </p>
          <p>
            <div class = "answer">
              <% @answer = question.answers.highest[0] %>
              <% if @answer == nil then %>
                No Answer
              <% else %>
                <%= render @answer %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </p>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Re-ask</a></li>
            <li><%= link_to raw("Answer"), new_answer_path(question_id: question.id), method: :get, class: "btn btn-default" %></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
     <% end %><-------Anchor tag
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```